# Infinite call to UseEffect UseSelector UseDispatch React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, frontend

Using the getContractsFromAPI action, I get a list of contracts that are in the API, then using useState and renderContracts, I display them on the page, but this starts an endless call to useEffect

```
const [contracts, setContracts] = useState({});
    

const contractsList = useAppSelector(({ contractsList }) => contractsList);

useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getContractsFromAPI());
    setContracts(contractsList);
}, [contractsList, dispatch]);

return (
    <div>
        <h2>Contracts:</h2>
        <ul className={styles.contractsList}>{renderContracts(contracts)}</ul>
    </div>
);
```

How can the problem be solved? I tried to remove [contractsList, dispatch] from useEffect, but then the initial render does not occur when the page is opened

Comment: Where do you get `contractsList` from anyway?

Comment: i edited my question, now you can see it

Comment: Is there a reason for you to copy it into state at all?

Comment: I tried render contractsList without useState, but it also triggers rerender

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't really need a shallow copy of the contracts in your component's local state, get rid of the local state and just use them from the selector.

```
function ContractsComponent() {
  const contracts = useAppSelector(({ contractsList }) => contractsList);

  // Get contracts from API on mount
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getContractsFromAPI());
  }, [dispatch]);

  if (!contracts) return <>Loading...</>;

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Contracts:</h2>
      <ul className={styles.contractsList}>{renderContracts(contracts)}</ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It's working!

Answer (score 3):

Put dispatch(getContractsFromAPI()); in it's own useEffect

```
useEffect(() => {
    setContracts(contractsList);
}, [contractsList, setContracts]);

useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getContractsFromAPI());
}, [dispatch, getContractsFromAPI]);
```

you were getting an infinite loop because getContractsFromAPI apparently edit contractsList. The easy solution is having getContractsFromAPI in a useEffect that does not watch for change on contractsList

UPDATE for anyone stumbling upon this answer: the user changed his question, adding more context between the time he posted his question and the time I posted my answer. My answer stays valid, but for the specific use case of @yourBadApple, AKX's answer is more relevant

Comment: Thanks! It's working! It's ok to use useEffect twice inside 1 component?

Comment: of course, you can use as many as you need. One piece of advice tho is to group the ones that have the same dependencies to watch